# Using an varray type in a select statement

Tags: arrays, select, plsql, oracle10g, varray

I am trying to use an varray-type in a select statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ARRAYTEST IS
  type array_t is varray(2) of int;
  array_test array_t := array_t(10,11);
BEGIN
  select * from STATISTIK where abschluss1 in array_test;
END;
```

But it is giving me an error:

```
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statement
```

The first Exception seems to be misleading, I don't want to select something into a variable I want an aquivalent of:

```
select * from STATISTIK where abschluss1 in (10,12);
```

But (10,12) substituted by an array (varray).

Is it possible to convert the varray to be used in a select-statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign a Select to a variable in a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260068/assign-a-select-to-a-variable-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: tl;dr you need to put the result of the select statement somewhere.

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicatie the mentioned question, because I don't want to select anything into an variable (see edits plz, but thanks for your answer anyway :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but your type must be global

```
create type array_t is varray(2) of int;
```

Then use array as a table (*open p for* only for compiling)

```
 declare
    array_test array_t := array_t(10,11);
p sys_refcursor;
    begin
open p for
       select * from STATISTIK where abschluss1 in (select column_value from table(array_test ));
    end;
```